# Converting unix command to windows

Tags: networking, command-line, windows

I have been provided a command to use in unix, however, I want to perfrom the same operation in windows. Is it possible ? It's a network configuration command that apparently interacts with a server ?

```
/sbin/ifconfig; uname -a
```

Comment: try `ipconfig /all` followed by `ver`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to be about Unix or Linux operating systems, but Windows. Questions about Windows can be asked on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Your commands do no sort of "server interaction", at least not in what most people would consider. They simply display networking information and the current kernel information.

In windows you can run `ipconfig /all` and a similiar command for `uname` would be `systeminfo`

You could always install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) and have those exact commands at your fingertips.